# Horse shoe lemma exercise from Weibel's Homological Algebra

Tags: homological-algebra

This is regarding the exercise 2.2.4 in Weibel's Introduction to homological Algebra which is about Horse shoe lemma for projective resolutions. That is if $0 \to A' \to A \to A'' \to 0$ is an exact sequence of R modules and if ${P'}_{.}$ and ${P''}_{.}$ and projective resolutions of $A'$ and $A''$ respectively then there is a projective resolution ${P}_{.}$ of A such that  $0 \to {P'}_{.} \to {P}_{.} \to {P''}_{.} \to 0$ is a split exact sequence of complexes. Proof I understood and the differentials for   ${P}_{.}$ are constructed step by step. But in the exercise he has given an explicit form for that. I am not able to prove that. Please help me.

Comment: Writing this out in detail here is really bothersome. You can probably find explicit formulas (which are not too relevant, anyways) in Jacobson's Basic Algebra II, I think.

Comment: It might be useful if you can either reproduce the form from the exercise or else give a link to page in an electronic copy of the book.  That way, people who do not have a copy of the book on hand can still try to offer help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Weibel's construction is perhaps a bit obscure (although effective if you mean to prove that such resolution exists in a quick way). The idea of the horseshoe lemma, among other things, is to obtain a split resolution of a given short exact sequence of modules. Thus, you want to define an appropriate differential $d : P'\oplus P'' \longrightarrow P'\oplus P''$ that make the desired diagram commute, where the resolution of your exact sequence is the (canonically) split exact sequence of complexes

$$ P' \longrightarrow P'\oplus P''\longrightarrow P''$$

You don't need to check the middle complex is a resolution once you obtained one, because it is automatically exact by the homology LES of the last short exact sequence.

If we write $\varepsilon',\varepsilon''$ for the augmentations for $A'$ and $A''$, then writing $\varepsilon_0'+\varepsilon_0''$ for the augmentation of $A$ where 
$$\varepsilon_0':P_0' \longrightarrow A$$
$$\varepsilon_0'':P_0'' \longrightarrow A$$

following the arrows gives

$$\varepsilon_0' =f\varepsilon'$$
$$\varepsilon ''\pi = g\varepsilon_0''$$

and because $P_0''$ is projective you can solve for $\varepsilon_0''$.
Now $d$ is a matrix of morphisms $\begin{pmatrix} f_1 & f_2 \\ g_1&g_2 \end{pmatrix}$. In particular, if we want commutativity at $P'$ we need that (follow the arrows, again)

$$f_1x'= d'x'$$
$$g_1x'=0$$

and commutativity at $P''$ gives that $g_2x''=d''x''$. We have shown that
$$d=\begin{pmatrix} d' & f_2 \\ 0&d'' \end{pmatrix}$$ 
which is what Weibel wanted.

Thus it suffices to determine $f_2:P''\longrightarrow P'$ inductively so that $d^2=0$, or, what is the same, so that
$$d'f_2 +f_2 d''=0$$
and I leave that to you. Note we already determined the map at degree $0$, where it looks a bit different. At any rate, the proof is an inductive lifting argument.